# Force a checkbox to always submit, even when unchecked

Tags: jquery, html, forms, input

I have an html form and i would like ALWAYS to have checkboxes to submit a value. How can i do that? I have one idea but i havent tried it and i am unsure if its the best way to do it (jquery to check if the box is checked or not, then set the value to 0/1 and check it off so it will submit)

Comment: Is there any reason you need unchecked boxes to submit? Seems like it's rather redundant, since you can detect if a checkbox wasn't checked by its presence/absence in the GET/POST data. If it's not there, it wasn't checked. If it's there, it was checked. Simple enough.

Comment: @Marc B: Using asp.net and firefox it looks like its ONLY there when it IS checked.

Comment: Yes, that's normal behavior. So your server-side script can assume that if the checkbox's name isn't present in the get/post data, then it wasn't checked on the client-side. This would be safer than using javascript to manipulate the submitted value.

Comment: @Marc B: The issue isnt if it is checked. Its if its present in the form or not. Thus my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTML doesn't work that way. HTML checkboxes are [specified](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox) as follows: if checked, then its `name=value` will be sent as request parameter. If unchecked, then its `name=value` will **not** be sent as request parameter. Note that when the `value` is unspecified, then most browsers default to "on". It's easier if you give all checkboxes the same `name` but a different and fixed `value`. This way you can obtain the checked ones as an array/collection.

If all checkboxes are already known beforehand in server side, you can just apply basic math to obtain the unchecked checkboxes:

```
uncheckedCheckboxes = allCheckboxes - checkedCheckboxes
```

If those checkboxes are created dynamically at the client side and therefore unknown beforehand in server side, then add for each checkbox a `<input type="hidden">` field containing information about the dynamically created checkbox, so that the server side knows which checkboxes are all present as the moment of submission.

Comment: "Since you already know beforehand which checkboxes are all in the HTML page" <--- not true in my case.

Comment: hmm, i would then get two values if checkbox is selected wouldnt i? The solution above already works.

Comment: No, just information about that "a checkbox" is present. The state of the view should be known in the server side. Truly, the solution of vassalis works, but it's actually not a solution, it's a workaround/hack. If your code is ever going to be decoupled, reused and/or maintained by others, they will fire you because of unintuitive behaviours.

Comment: vassilis worked but you can see the checkbox being checked off so that may freak ppl out. So i created your solution which actually is a great idea. But i only create the input if the checkbox is off. Problem is i need to remove it when i hit back otherwise i get multiple values. So i am figuring that out now.

Comment: It's not necessary to add/remove them like that. You could also just keep them as "all checkboxes" and use the values of the checked checkboxes as "checked checkboxes". During submit processing, you can extract the "unchecked checkboxes" from it.

Comment: What i do is inject a hidden input when there is an unchecked checkbox and set the name to the same name and use the value "" (or alternatively 0). Then to combat hitting back, earlier in the submit i use this solution to remove it. It works very well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748340/multiple-attr-selector-in-jquery

Comment: If those checkboxes are created dynamically at the client side with a name like, lets say, `MyDestArray[`], in order to be processed in a server-side language like, let's say, PHP, intending to be treated as an unindexed array, then adding an `<input type="hidden">` for each checkbox will end up adding TWO array elements for each checked checkbox, thus ending with an array of results greater than the number of checkboxes you have to check in.

Comment: @Pere: I recite *"If you tell a bit more about the server side language you're using to process the form, we would be able to give more tips/tricks how to achieve this the best way.
"*. One way would be storing `allCheckboxes` in the view state. Hidden inputs is one way to transfer view state around. How good/bad **you** utilize it doesn't make the answer good/bad.

Comment: Even better: why cannot we have a simple `alwayssend` attribute like `readonly` or `disabled` we can set to `true` or `false`? W3C, are you there?

Comment: @Pere: the server can this way not anymore distinguish which ones are checked.

Answer (score 15):

Thanks to [@Lazarus' idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102544/set-unchecked-value-of-checkbox/5102615#5102615), also mentioned by [@BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746678/force-a-checkbox-to-always-submit/3746833#3746833), you can add an additional control to the form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="checkbox1" value="off">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="on"> My checkbox
```

Checkbox and the hidden fields must have the same name. The hidden input is always submitted as a default value. If the checkbox is checked then also it's submitted. So you have a list of 2 values for parameter "checkbox1", that you have to treat at server side.

...maybe a `<select>` tag would be more handy.

Comment: Not valid for unindexed arrays, as you will end up having two values for each checked element.

Comment: @Pere Won't you always just receive one value anyways? Either the `off` from the input field (if the checkbox is off) or the overridden `on` from checkbox?

Comment: This way always the hidden "off" value gets read first for me - making my request parameter false all the time.
My solution: changing the order of these lines: so the hidden line comes after the normal one. Then when the box is checked, that value will come and be read first!

Answer (score 12):

There is a legitimate reason for asking for something like this, although the behaviour envisioned here is not the right way to go about it. There is a problem with the checkbox when used correctly *when editing existing data* and that's that there is no way to determine whether no value was submitted because the field was not present on the form or because the user cleared all of the values. You can run into this sort of problem any time you include fields conditionally.

One could go to the trouble of maintaining a "view state", of course, but it's much easier to include a hidden "companion field" whenever a checkbox or select with the multiple option (which is also excluded when all selections are cleared) is displayed. The field should have a related but different name (a name from which the actual field name can be extracted). The Lotus Domino server has used fields named %%Surrogate_FieldNameHere for this purpose since (I believe) version 7 for exactly the reason I described here.

Comment: GREAT! point. Thats exactly why i need it, if its present or not.

Answer (score 10):

To tell you the truth, this feels like a big no-no.

Anyway here goes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('form').submit(function() {
        $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
            $(this).attr('value', $(this).is(':checked') ? '1' : '0');
            $(this).attr('checked', true);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: As @BalusC noted this goes vertically against the specification for the behavior of the checkbox. This kinda of ninja-tweaking is how major screw-ups are born.

Comment: It turns out i cant use it. When submitting you can see the checkboxes being checked off and that might freak some people out.

Comment: This solution will make the user see that all checkboxes are checked for the moment before the page reloads. This will lead to confusion.

Answer (score 5):

Although this goes against the HTML spec, if you know what you are doing, using this you no longer have to cater checkboxes which are handled completely differently when submitted - and for example naming fields `with_brackets[]` can actually be useable.

### Complete solution

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form', function() {
    $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
        var checkbox = $(this);

        // add a hidden field with the same name before the checkbox with value = 0
        if ( !checkbox.prop('checked') ) {
            checkbox.clone()
                .prop('type', 'hidden')
                .val(0)
                .insertBefore(checkbox);
        }
    });
});
```

**Take note:** the non-checked checkboxes now submit a value of `"0"`

---

Additionally, if you want to change the behaviour of a single form only, just alter the *first line* in the above snippet:

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form.your-class-name', function() {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: I'm very sure the downvote is by one of the authors of rival answers, thanks for playing fair.

Answer (score 2):

if you have many checkbox, you can try this code:

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="$(this).next().val(this.checked?1:0)"/> <input type="hidden" name="checkbox1[]"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the following HTML:

```
<form id="myform" method="post" action="my/url">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" name="checkbox1"/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" name="checkbox2"/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3" name="checkbox3"/>
</form>
```

**Normal form submit:**

On form submit, before submitting, change all values of checkboxes to 0 and 1 based on if checkbox is unchecked or checked. Like so:

```
$('#myform').submit(function() {
    var $checkboxes = $('#myform').find('input[type="checkbox"]');// Select all checkboxes
    $checkboxes.filter(':checked').val(1);// Set value to 1 for checked checkboxes
    $checkboxes.not(':checked').val(0);// Set value to 0 for unchecked checkboxes
    $checkboxes.prop('checked', true);// Change all checkboxes to "checked" so all of them are submitted to server
});
```

Note: Ugly thing about this code, while form is submitting, all checkboxes will appear as "checked" for a moment. But if you apply same concept for ajax form submit, it would be better.

**AJAX form submit:**

```
$.post('my/url', {
    'checkbox1': $('#checkbox1').is(':checked') ? 1 : 0,
    'checkbox2': $('#checkbox2').is(':checked') ? 1 : 0,
    'checkbox3': $('#checkbox3').is(':checked') ? 1 : 0
}, function(response) {
    // Server JSON response..
}, 'json');
```