# multiple attr selector in jquery?

Tags: jquery

How can i do this in jquery?

```
$('#SomeId input[type="hidden" AND name="somename"]')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('#SomeId input[type="hidden"][name="somename"]')
```

Comment: An alternative is `input:hidden[name="somename"]`.

Comment: @BalusC - yeah, I was thinking of that, but just want to go with the OP's example. ;)