# set unchecked value of checkbox

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc

Is there a way of setting the default unchecked value of a checkbox?
Am not using a databound control.
This is passing data from a form and would like it to pass false as opposed to null when unchecked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, using the default `HtmlHelpers` will achieve this for you

```
<%: Html.Checkbox("myCheckbox") %>
```

or with Razor

```
@Html.Checkbox("myCheckbox")
```

The `Checkbox()` method will render a `input type="hidden"` field along side the input `type="checkbox"` that will submit the value `false` when the checkbox is unchecked.

```
<input id="myCheckbox" name="myCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="true" />
<input name="myCheckbox" type="hidden" value="false" />
```

If you want to submit a value other than `false` then you should render the checkbox and hidden field yourself setting the value of the hidden field to your default value.  Note that they must have the same name attribute.

Comment: I completely missed the mvc tag. Doh! ;)

Comment: I've found that using the hidden value technique only works when the hidden input value comes first in the form (tested on Chrome 18 only).

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by adding an additional control to the form thus:

```
<input type="hidden" name="checkbox1" value="off">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="on"> My checkbox
```

That way you have a default value for your checkbox should it not be checked. If it is checked then the checkbox overrides the hidden field, for this to work the checkbox and the hidden field **must** have the same name.

Comment: Are you sure about that? Usually when you have double elements with the same name, they'll get sent to the server as some form of array.

Comment: @Sam Yes, this is the way ASP.NET MVC does it when using the @Html.CheckBox() HtmlHelper method.

Comment: @David Glenn: For two checkboxes it looks like form submit returns "false,on" in post data if checkbox is checked and "false" if not checked. jquery serialize() method seems to return "on" only if checkbox is selected in this case. So this is a bit incorrect answer

Comment: Yes, I tried this and the form passed both values to the response rather than have the checkbox value override the hidden value. Doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I did it using Razor , works for me

Getting Value

```
bool CashOnDelivery = Product.CashOnDelivery == null ? false : Convert.ToBoolean(Product.CashOnDelivery);
```

Razor View

```
@Html.CheckBox("CashOnDelivery", CashOnDelivery) (Not nullable bit)
```

Razor don't support nullable bool

In C# side

```
 Insert.CashOnDelivery = Convert.ToBoolean(Collection["CashOnDelivery"].Contains("true")?true:false);
```