# How to submit unchecked checkbox also

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

If checkbox is not checked, clicking on form submit button does not submit any data.

Some checkboxes may be not present in form depending on form fields selected by user. So submit controller has no possibility to determine if the unchecked checkbox was present in form or not.

If database contains true for this column, this property is not updated to false.
Checkbox name is same as database boolean column name.

How to to force form to submit checkboxes which are in unchecked state or any other idea to 
set value in database to false if checkbox is not checked but not to change value in database if checkbox is not present in form ?

jquery, jqueryui, asp.net 2 mvc are used

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a common issue with checkboxes in HTML forms and isn't unique to ASP.NET.

The answer is to have a hidden field that accompanies each checkbox. When the checkbox is modified, use a client-side event to update the hidden field.

The hidden field will always be submitted.

However, since you're using ASP.NET MVC, if you use the `HTML.CheckBoxFor` helper, it will handle this for you automatically.

Comment: @Thank you, this solves the issue. I'm generating dynamic form in asp.net MVC2 like `void RenderFormField(StringBuilder sb) {
            switch (col.ColumnType)
            {
                case ColumnType.Boolean:
                    sb.AppendFormat("<input type='hidden' value='false' name='{0}' />", col.PropertyName);

                    sb.AppendFormat("<input type='checkbox' id='{0}' name='{0}' ", col.PropertyName);
                       sb.Append("disabled='disabled' ");
`. Is it reasonable/how to replace stringbuilder with CheckBoxFor or other helper in this case ?

Comment: @Andrus, I suggest you create a regular view using the aforementioned `HTML.CheckBoxFor` and copy the resulting HTML (and ensuring you catch any Javascript inclusion). However, as a general rule, I'd try to avoid generating a form this way. Maybe worth opening up another question detailing what you're trying to achieve if you want to investigate other options. Good luck!

Comment: why client-side event in required? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102544/set-unchecked-value-of-checkbox  answer wrote that nothing more is required, hidden element with same name is sufficient since it will overrridden always !?

Comment: I think you're right and it's simply exploiting some behaviour when the name of the checkbox and the name of the hidden fields are the same.

Comment: For two checkboxes it looks like form submit returns "false,on" in post data if checkbox is checked and "false" if not checked. jquery serialize() method seems to return "on" only if checkbox is selected in this case.

Comment: If you have 2 elements with same name they are both posted to the server with a value of like 0,1

Answer (score 7):

This is a very common problem - when checkbox isn't selected it wont send to server value      off/ false by itself. Most popular answer that I found was to add hidden field with the same name as checkbox and value = false. But then when someone checked it it sent me two values.

And I didn't like it. This is what I did:

**Somewhere in HTML:**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="${name}" onclick="true" >
```

**In JQuery:**

First step is to set hidden values on all checkboxes that aren't checked.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".checkbox").each(function () {
                 if ($(this).prop("checked") == undefined) {
                    $(this).after("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"" + $(this).attr("name") + "\" value="off">")
                 }
              }
        )
     });
```

Secondly we have to react on user clicking the check-box: while unselecting add hidden field, when selecting - remove next sibling in DOM - we expected hidden field there.

**WARNING**: when check-boxes have common parent you should check if next sibling's type is hidden and then remove it!:

```
   $(".checkbox").click(function () {
                    if ($(this).prop("checked") == undefined) {
                       $(this).after("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"" + $(this).attr("name") + "\" value=off>")
                    } else {
                       $(this).next().remove();
                    }
                 }
           );
```

And it works for me :)

Comment: I upvoted you because this is an elegant solution. Maybe it's not best for .net but I'm not using .net. However, a couple notes: there is no need for the 'onclick' in your HTML and it is bad form besides. Also, unfortunately your code doesn't quite work, at least with the latest jQuery (attr("checked") doesn't work anymore). I will edit your answer with my suggested improvements (which work for me). Thanks for your answer, it was very helpful.

Comment: I've never had an edit rejected until now, but 3 times I've tried to correct your answer (attr -> prop) but it has been rejected every time. Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm sure they'll allow you to correct your answer; please do.

Comment: Thank you for information :) I edited my answer. I'm also not using this solution for .net, but I think this problem is more global one.

Comment: This is pretty clever. Thanks. I know it's old as dirt but some of us are still using classic asp... :(

Answer (score 3):

My shortest solution: use a checkbox's onchange() event to set a hidden sibling to 0 or 1. As follows:

```
var htm = '<input type="checkbox" '+(isMale>0?"checked":"")+' onchange="this.nextSibling.value=this.checked==true?1:0;" /><input type="hidden" name="Gender" value="'+isMale+'" />';
```

Submit ONLY sends the hidden sibling, NOT the checkbox because it has no name attribute. So the above is serialized as "...&Gender=1..." or "...&Gender=0..." depending on isMale value.

Answer (score 2):

I found myself in this issue recently, and this is my solution.
I do it without hidden field.
Just change the 'value' of the checkbox to 'off', and make sure it is checked so it is sent.
Note: I have only tested against a php server, but it should work.

```
        // Prepare checkboxes
    var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]')
    checkboxes.forEach(function(cbox) {
        if (!cbox.checked) { // If the checkbox is checked it keeps its value, default value is 'on' 
            cbox.value='off' // Otherwise change the value to off, or something else
            cbox.checked = true // We need to check it, so it sends the value
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue while using jQuery/Java - Instead of using an additional hidden field, I forced a submission each time the form was saved irrespective of whether fields were modified.

e.g. If `chkBox1 =unchecked` (will send null - control value attribute via jQuery onClick or onChange event of checkbox)

```
<input name="chkBox1 " class="editable-value" id="chkBox1 " style="display: inline;" type="checkbox" data-type="A" data-original-value="checked" data-force-save="true" value="N"/>
```

and `ChkBox2=checked` (Will send Y)

```
<input name="ChkBox2" class="editable-value" id="ChkBox2" type="checkbox" CHECKED="Y" data-type="A" data-original-value="checked" value="Y">
```

are the on screen values and I try to save the data,in my Java code I perform a null check on the value obtained in the getter and interpret a null as an 'N'.
This avoids the overhead of a hidden field although one is free to choose the solution that addresses their particular situation.

Answer (score 0):

My form is created dynamically, so incorporating additional hidden fields would have been quite complicated. For me it works by temporarily altering the field type in a submit handler of the form.

```
myForm.addEventHandler("submit", ev => {
    for (let oField of ev.target.elements) {
        if (oField.nodeName.toUpperCase() === "INPUT" &&
                oField.type === "checkbox" &&
                ! oField.checked) {
            oField.type = "text";    // input type text will be sent
                         // After submitting, reset type to checkbox
            oReq.addEventListener("loadstart",
                        () => { oField.type = "checkbox"; });
        }
    }
});
```

This feels a bit dirty, but works for my.

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is old and pretty much dead but, I ran into this problem as well (yeah in 2021!). I had to remove the name attribute from the checkbox as my work around.

In your razor page code:

```
@model MyViewModel

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.MyCheckbox)
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.MyCheckbox)
...
...
...
@* script tag at bottom of razor page *@
<script>
document.getElementById('MyCheckbox').removeAttribute('name');
document.getElementById('MyCheckbox').addEventListener('click', function() {
   // razor should create a hidden field with the name of the checkbox immediately 
   // after the checkbox.
   this.nextSibling.value = this.checked;
});
</script>
```

The checkbox will no longer get validated or submitted because there is no name attribute but the hidden field (which has the same name the checkbox had) will.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but maybe someone like a solution likes this:

```
<form action="<your url>" method="get" onsubmit="return setupSearch();">
<input
    id="cache"
    name="cache"
    type="checkbox"
    style="display: none" />
<input
    id="archive"
    name="archive"
    type="checkbox" />
```

Javascript function:

```
function setupSearch() {
    document.getElementById("cache").checked = !document.getElementById("archive").checked;
    return true;
}
```

As a result you get the following values in your query string:

```
?cache=on
```

or just

```
?archive=on
```