# Complicated Viewstate issue on dynamic controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, user-controls

I have a control that is loaded dynamically and contains a repeater amongst other items such as a group of text boxes.

The control is used for address verification.

The process is:

1. control displays.
2. User enters the address info.
3. page posts back and the control validates the address info against a web service.
4. If the address isn't 100%, it displays a list of potential matches.  <- this occurs in a repeater.  In other words, it is databound in code.
5. The user checks a box next to the one they want to accept.
6. page posts back

So far, 1 - 6 work.  The problem is that when the page posts back, there are no repeater items.

How can I get the repeater to load it's items without having to run another databind() operation?

Failing that, how can I run the databind() effectively?  In other words, I don't have the controls street/city/state/zip values during the oninit.  So, how can I reapply the viewstate changes?

Comment: You should certainly be able to grab the value the user selected; it will be in the Request.Forms collection as it's a checkbox. If you can just grab that value and continue, do you need to rebuild the entire control?

Comment: @dash:  That is viable.  How do I know the name of that checkbox?  It's inside a repeater on a dynamically loaded user control..

Comment: @dash: I ended up using your idea.  I iterated through request.forms looking for a field that ended in the name of my checkbox. Once I found that I was able to test it and get some surrounding data.  Works pretty well.  Move your comment to an answer and I'll accept.  Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most controls are rendered as HTML form elements like `<input type="text" name="myId" id="myId/>`.

Part of Web Forms is really just a wrapper around all of this.

Whenever you need to get at the raw values, you can just look in the Request.Forms collection for any control values that are posted back with the name of the control you are looking for (which will usually be made up of the unique id that asp.net generates for uniqueness of controls, and your name).

This is exactly what you did - you went through the Forms collection looking at the raw form values that were POSTed to the server. It's also what you often do when you implement the IPostBackDataHandler interface when creating your own controls - you scoop the value out of Request.Forms.

The annoying thing with checkboxes is that with "standard" HTML they [only get submitted if they are ticked.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7600817/how-to-submit-unchecked-checkbox-also)

Comment: In this case, it's okay if the checkboxes aren't there when submitted.  I'm just trying to find the first instance of one that is checked.  Worked perfect.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Two important facts:

1. Controls in a Repeater Item should be created in **OnItemCreated** and *not* **OnItemDataBound**.
2. **OnItemCreated** runs during a Postback *without* one having to call **DataBind()**.

I've been loading user controls into repeater items and the type of user control is based on the data item being bound to the repeater. So I added the type of user control into the repeater item's viewstate so that during the OnItemCreated that runs on postback (without a data item to bind to because DataBind() has not been called) it knows what type of user control to load. The viewstate will then be applied.

```
protected void rpTransactions_OnItemCreated(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            var dataItem = e.Item.DataItem;

            string typeName;

            string viewStateKey = string.Concat("typeName", e.Item.ItemIndex);

            if (dataItem == null)
            {
                typeName = ViewState[viewStateKey].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                typeName = dataItem.GetType().ToString();

                ViewState[viewStateKey] = typeName;
            }

            Control template = TransactionTemplateFactory(typeName);

            template.ID = "trans";

            e.Item.FindControl("phTransSpecific").Controls.Add(template);
        }
    }
```

If the code in OnItemDataBound runs, it fishes this user control out and binds its data to it.