# When validator in yii2 not working properly

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

On one of my `view` file in project i am using `when` validator for defining some validation for a `model` but its not working properly may be because i dont know how to use that validator. Here is the model code of that table

```
       return [
        [['event_id', 'user_id'], 'required'],
        [['event_id', 'user_id'], 'integer'],
        [['is_mandatory'], 'boolean'],
        [['answer'], 'string', 'max' => 250],
        [['answer'], 'required', 'when' => function($model){
            return $model->is_mandatory == 1; }]
    ];
```

Here is my `view` code and yes i am creating this field on the view file with the instance because to create those fields depends on other inputs.

```
        $modelAnswers = new Answers();
        $modelAnswers->is_mandatory = 0;

        echo $form->field($modelAnswers, "answer",[
            'template' => ' <div class="row"><div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6"><label>{label}</label></div><div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-8">{input}{error}{hint}</div></div>'
        ])->textInput(['maxlength' => true]);
```

But it always prints the field as required. I can see in the debugger that `$model` is assigned the value correctly. Whats wrong with the validator here??

Comment: `$modelAnswers->is_mandatory = 0;` and `$model->is_mandatory == 1;`. The code you posted in `when` never will be completed with this conditions. Post controller code.

Comment: @ineersa i am creating this instance on the view page. So there is nothing in Controller related to `Answers` model. And i am creating it on the `view` page because it depends on other input weather to generate that field or not.

Comment: Again you set `$modelAnswers->is_mandatory` to `0` and asking it to be `1`. How your condition can be true?

Comment: @ineersa actually i set it static just to post it on stack. Otherwise its value will be set by a query. and query will return either 0 or 1.

Comment: @ineersaa and if the value is set to `0` than it should be not required but regardless any condition i provide,its is printed as required value on the form.

Comment: Does your query returns 1? Dump `$modelAnswers->is_mandatory` in controller before validation. What's there?

Comment: @ineersa there is nothing in controller which affects `$modelAnswers`. I create instance and provide its value just to trigger `when` condition from the `view` file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97821/discussion-between-ineersa-and-mike-ross).

Comment: Have you put the is_mandatory field anywhere on your form?

Comment: refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29888182/yii2-custom-validator-not-working-as-guide-suggests

Comment: @JoeMiller i havent and i am assigning value of `is_mandatory` on the form.

Answer (score 1):

The `when()` validation is only there for server-side validation, and will only evaluate when the form is submitted. If you want to display the field as required or not depending on the value of `is_mandatory` then you have two options.

Firstly, you can use the `whenClient()` method to add client-side validation. This is what I use on my own forms, and involves writing a javascript function that will determine if the field is required or not, and it will then apply the relvant classes. To do this, you will need to include the `is_mandatory` field somewhere on your form, probably as a hidden field, and you wil need to enable clientValidation on the form.

Secondly, you could simply adapt the template for the field so that the  error messages are not included unless `is_mandatory` is set to true. This will involve rewriting the field label.

```
echo $form->field($modelAnswers, "answer",[
            'template' => ' <div class="row"><div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6"><label class="{$modelAnswers->is_mandatory ? 'required' : ''}">Name of label here</label></div><div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-8">{input}{error}{hint}</div></div>'
        ])
```

Comment: i like the second idea better. Because writing java script for the fields that are not event assigned a id yet is a bit difficult for me. I am going to try second method

Comment: its throwing syntax error. And i also tried just typing `<label class="{required}">` but its not working ,i dont know how its gonna work anyway.