# Checkbox do not save value if not checked/unchecked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox

I have a form with checkbox inputs. If the checkbox is not checked or unchecked by hand, it will not save the value in the submit handling.

this is the checkbox input field:

```html
const CheckBoxField = ({ name, placeholder, isChecked, handleChange }) => {
    return (
<div class="input-div">
<label>{name}</label>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        name={name}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        defaultChecked={false}
        value={false}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
    </div>
);}

export default CheckBoxField;
```

and here i am using the chechbox component:

```html
 if (input[form].input_type === "checkbox") {
                    return (
                      <CheckBoxField
                        name={input[form].name}
                        placeholder={input[form].placeholder}
                        required={input[form].required}
                        key={input[form].placeholder}
                        isChecked={true}
                        handleChange={handleChange}
                      />
                    );
                  }
```

and my handlechange function:

```html
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.name, event.target.value)
    const inputs =
    event.target.type === "checkbox" ? event.target.checked : event.target.value
    setValue({ ...value, [event.target.name]: inputs });
  };
```

I do not understand what i am missing. I have a defaultChecked to false, which should be the one that set a value if none is chosen, or what?

please help me

Comment: Yeah I have faced that issue if I remember correcly. In the function you send or use the values, just check if the checkbox is undefined define that variable to 0. Or you can try on document ready to set all to unchecked.

Comment: That's how checkboxes work; unchecked boxes don't send a value to the submit handler. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7600817/how-to-submit-unchecked-checkbox-also for example

Comment: (Unrelated, but note also your CheckBoxField component does nothing with its `isChecked` prop, it will never load as checked)

Comment: Yes @DanielBeck is right. I think you need to pass `checked={isChecked}` on <input />

Answer (score -1):

Because the property: name, value, type, checked, do not exist in the `target` object. Use `currentTarget` instead of `target`, then the properties will be defined.

```js
const [value, setValue] = useState();

const handleChange = (event) => {
    //console.log(event.currentTarget.name, event.currentTarget.value)
    const inputs =
        event.currentTarget.type === "checkbox" ? event.currentTarget.checked : event.currentTarget.value
    setValue({ ...value, [event.currentTarget.name]: inputs });

};

useEffect(() => {
    console.log(value);
}, [value])
```

```
logs:
> {onChange: true}
> {onChange: false}
```