# Why checkbox not submitting any data at onchange when being unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, web2py

Using Web2Py I constructed some checkboxes, they all look similar to this one:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="some_value" onchange="ajax('/app/controller/function/args', ['the_name'])" name="the_name" id="some_id" class="boolean">
```

They are supposed to submit their value on change, which they do. When I `print request.vars`:

```
<Storage {'the_name': some_value}>
```

but only when they are being checked or activated.

The other way, when they are unchecked or deactivated the ajax call is done, but no data submitted. Again `print request.vars`:

```
<Storage {}>
```

Why is this only working 'one-way'?

**Edit:**

The behaviour stays the same when using the default-value `value="on"`. To specify what I am doing: I have a number of hidden checkoxes that get checked / unchecked on button-clicks. When the checkboxes are not hidden and clicked directly the behaviour does not change - submitting data on activation, not submitting any data on deactivation.
Here is the JS I use.

```
$(function() {
    return $('.btn-trigger').click(function() {
        var btn, checkbox;
        btn = $(this);
        checkbox = btn.next();
        if (checkbox.attr('checked')) {
            checkbox.val('false');
            checkbox.removeAttr('checked').prop('checked', false);
            checkbox.trigger('change');
            return btn.removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-danger');
        } else {
            checkbox.val('true');
            checkbox.attr('checked', 'checked').prop('checked', true);
            checkbox.trigger('change');
            return btn.removeClass('btn-danger').addClass('btn-success');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to pass a hidden input field along the checkbox. Both, the checkbox and the hidden field must share the same name:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="some_value" onchange="ajax('/app/controller/function/args', ['the_name'])" name="the_name" id="some_id" class="boolean">
<input type="hidden" name="the_name value="some_value">
```

Now, if the checkbox is deactivated (is unchecked) the value from the hidden field is passed:

```
<Storage {'the_name': some_value}>
```

on activating the values from both fields are passed:

```
<Storage {'the_name': [some_value, some_value]}>
```

[This post pointed to the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102544/set-unchecked-value-of-checkbox).