# Trying to pass 0 with POST data for unchecked checkboxes

Tags: jquery, post, checkbox

I have a page where the user can dynamically (jQuery) create a table.  It will later be submitted as a form.

Some of the table cells may have a checkbox in it.  Not all table rows will have that checkbox.  My goal is to include in the POST data, all three possible states so that my POST arrays all have the same number of items.

1. checkbox present and checked = `1`
2. checkbox present and not checked = `0`
3. checkbox not present = `0`

There is a [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/heidilux/9gALc/) with the basic mechanics set up (got some of the fiddle js from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3746764/1440617)).  Not sure how I can illustrate the form submitting with it though.

If I add three items to the table (based on the ordered list above) in various combinations I get different results, as such...

- All three items are #1 =

  ```
  ["add_logo"] array(3) {
  [0] "1"
  [1] "1"
  [2] "1"
  }
  ```
- All three items are #3 =

  ```
  ["add_logo"] array(3) {
  [0] "0"
  [1] "0"
  [2] "0"
  }
  ```
- All three items are #2 = `nothing is POSTed`
- Add items 2, 1, 3 = `item with unchecked checkbox not included`

  ```
  ["add_logo"] array(2) {
  [0] "1"
  [1] "0"
  }
  ```

And so on...  Basically, it seems that I'm not sending unchecked checkboxes at all.  I guess I just don't understand why the `each()` bit works in-so-far as it can change the value from `on` to `1`, but can't set the value to `0`.

I tried the hidden input bit to get over this hump, but it's not working for me... I'm thinking because there is nothing really unique about each form entry?

Lastly, if I add the `$(this).attr('checked', true);` like in the answer I linked, it just sets all checkbox values to `1`.

Comment: Your "each" function is looping over checkboxes...

 $('input:checkbox[name^=add_logo]').each(...

... but as you said, some rows don't have checkboxes (i.e. they are not "logoable"), so your each iterator skips those rows. That's why these rows don't get added to your POST payload. Instead of a hidden input field, you might try adding a hidden input type checkbox with style="display:none" and name^=add_logo so that it gets "found" by the each iterator.

Comment: Here's an updated fiddle showing this approach. Instead of just submitting the form, I'm actually constructing an object that can be serialized and sent in an AJAX request. http://jsfiddle.net/9gALc/23/

Comment: @crickkills Thanks for the feedback.  To your first comment, actually, the rows that are not logoable (no checkbox, just a hidden field) _are_ POSTing as they should.  It's only the checkboxes present but not checked that are not posting.  Thanks for the suggestion about the display:none.  I'll definitely give that a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it...

It seems I wasn't able to set the value of an unchecked checkbox.  From all the other questions I've read, I guess I'm not surprised.  Those unchecked checkboxes are just not POSTed, no matter what value you give them.

In the end, I made a change to the code executed upon submitting the form.  I changed the ternary from trying to set the value to `0` if the box was unchecked, to just removing the checkbox and replacing it with a hidden field, if it was unchecked.

So from this...

```
$("#submit").click(function () {
    $('input:checkbox[name^=add_logo]').each(function () {
        $(this).attr('value', $(this).is(':checked') ? '1' : '0');
    });
});
```

... to this ...

```
$("#submit").click(function () {
    $('input:checkbox[name^=add_logo]').each(function () {
        $(this).prop("checked") ? $(this).attr('value','1') : $(this).html("<input type='hidden' name='add_logo[]' value='0' />");
    });
});
```

I'm pretty green when it comes to jQuery/javascript, so I'm not sure if that'll come back to bite me, but I haven't been able to break it yet.